# CANDY chat with Openfire: how can I can send "read message state" to openfire?

Tags: javascript, openfire, candy

how can I can send "read message state" to openfire?

A: msg1 -> B:
A: msg2 -> B:

B: ok -> A:

When B send msg "ok", I also want to send "read message state" of (msg1, msg2) to A

Anyone know something that would a great help! :-D

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the relevant code you have made?

Comment: :-D maybe some code in the candy.js